# Android user receipt validation

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've developed an app for Android and it's already been released on Google Store. Today I got an email from user telling me they bought one of in-app product but didn't get it.

They sent me a receipt that look like following.

[image]

How can I check to see if this receipt is genuine and belongs to my app?